# Transclusion in AngularJS, repeat multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angularjs 1.6, I made this transclusion type of thing.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {

            $scope.testmodel1 = {
                testmodel1prop: "testmodel1prop"
            };

            $scope.testmodel2 = {
                testmodel2prop: "testmodel2prop"
            }
        })

        app.directive('tabs', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {},
                transclude: true  ,

                link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
                    // transcluded content's scope should inherit from parent
                    transcludeFn(scope.$parent, function (clonedTranscludedContent) {

                        var tabs = [];

                        for (var i = 1; i < clonedTranscludedContent.length; i = i + 2) {
                            tabs.push(clonedTranscludedContent[i]);
                        }

                        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                            debugger;
                            var jqueryTab =  $(clonedTranscludedContent[1]);
                            var stringTab = jqueryTab.prop('outerHTML');
                            var model = jqueryTab.attr('model');
                            var pocoModelFromParent = scope.$parent[model];
                            var newScope = angular.merge(scope.$parent.$new(), pocoModelFromParent)

                            var linkFn = $compile(stringTab);
                            var compiledContent = linkFn(newScope);
                            el.append(compiledContent);

                        }

                    });
                }
            };
        });


        app.directive('test', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {},
                link: function ($scope, $element, attr) {
                    $scope.var1 = "test";
                },
                template: '<p>{{ var1 }}</p>'
            };
        });





<div ng-app="plunker" >

        <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

            <tabs>

                <tab model="testmodel1" title="tab2">{{ testmodel1prop }}</tab>

                <tab model="testmodel2" title="tab1"> {{ testmodel2prop }} </tab>

            </tabs>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to get some feedback if this is okay or not.

It works perfectly by the way.

The first thing that pops into my mind is why does 'clonedTranscludedContent' has a sort of empty object at position 1 3 5 7 and so on.I have yet to figure out what that is, probably the ::before in chrome?

I am planning to use this on production actually.

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element by using the content property.